# Can I use two javax @BeanParam beans in the same method signature?

Tags: java, cxf

We are using Spring and Apache cxf.

For the following example code, I get an exception. Which makes me wonder: can I use two BeanParam annotations/beans in the same method signature?

```
import javax.ws.rs.BeanParam;
//...
@GET
@Produces({"application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
public Response doFoo(
        @BeanParam Bar bar,
        @BeanParam Bas bas,
        @Context UriInfo uriInfo)
        throws BazException {
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: null
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toInternalServerErrorException(SpecExceptions.java:77) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toInternalServerErrorException(ExceptionUtils.java:110) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.createBeanParamValue(JAXRSUtils.java:975) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:767) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:716) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:265) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
```

In JAXRSUtils, I can see this:

```
BeanParamInfo bmi = ProviderFactory.getInstance(m).getBeanParamInfo(clazz);
if (bmi == null) {
    // we could've started introspecting now but the fact no bean info 
    // is available indicates that the one created at start up has been 
    // lost and hence it is 500
    LOG.warning("Bean parameter info is not available");
    throw ExceptionUtils.toInternalServerErrorException(null, null);
}
```

Which is the exception that gets thrown.

Is there any hint in this on what I'm doing wrong? Things seem to work when I comment out the `@BeanParam Bas bas,` line... Am I maybe not allowed to use two `@BeanParam` in the same method signature? (I couldn't find any hint that I wouldn't be, though...)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to do what you want to do and cxf isn't able to allow you to have two BeanParams, in the end I ended up using inheritance between the two classes even though that gave less flexibility. That may not be an option in your case depending on what your objects represent.

Answer (score 0):

We are working with Christian on it on CXF users list. The recent test confirms it works. Christian - please respond to my clarification request.